# Uses for tracks in 9648

Tags: nxt, technic, piece-information, sets, education

Has anyone used the Tank tracks (429139) from Lego education set 9648 for anything other than a tank?

The tracks are fixed in size, and I've found the application rather limited (driver belt, track) so far.

At this stage they seem to be a bit of a novelty - so any feedback welcome!

Comment: I couldn't find the part '429139' in that set, are you referring to this [piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1681&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)?

Comment: I was suspecting [part 57518](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57518&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) was what they meant, but it is not clear.

Comment: @chicks I couldn't find those in the set referenced.

Comment: Yes, that's the part... the set is a LEGO education set - not sure it the part numbers differ as I took it straight from the included part sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My FIRST LEGO League team likes to use them as clothing accessories, like belts, headbands, sashes, etc.

More commonly, though, they are used for conveyor belts (for example, in a [great ball contraption](http://greatballcontraption.com/wiki/Main_Page)). You can also use them for a chain drive when 3711 is not strong enough or big enough.

I also saw [this](https://www.facebook.com/xrizenzo.et/posts/1390053017769621) recently where small carriages were attached to the links and it was used as a vertical parking system for matchbox cars.

Comment: +1, threads like these are used all the time in GBC modules. Although not as versatile as [Technic Tread Links](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=57518&idColor=85#T=C&C=85) they are slightly smaller in width which could be an advantage for smaller models. They can also be used as conveyor belts as shown in the Toy Story set [Trash Compactor Escape](https://brickset.com/sets/7596-1/Trash-Compactor-Escape)

Answer (score 1):

I think someone years ago use them for a machine gun design that actually worked, they placed shooting pieces upon the track and ran it through a special gear worked mechanism that pushed the triggers on top of individual shooters, I think it could fire over 500 a minute, not much of a range but it did look pretty good fun. (forbidden lego of course!)

Comment: Forbidden lego?